# How receive bytes using FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, stream, ftpwebrequest

I am coding my first main project; an FTP client. I have managed to get it to connect, and request a listing of all files etc (working on properly formatting dirs xD) but it got me wondering, when I request a file I read the response to a `Stream`. Now I understand a lot of people use `StreamReader` but this is for text and not binary files? So how does an FTP server send the data exactly? Can I assume if I read straight from the Stream everything will be ok to place into a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed if you use the `StreamReader`, it will try to interpret the bytes in the `Stream` as text. What means, it will try to interpret it according to a particular encoding (the UTF-8 by default). What is not good idea, if the actual data are binary.

See the [`StreamReader` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader):

> Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding.

There's no point reading the `Stream` with the `StreamReader`, if you want to access the stream byte-wise. That's, what the `Stream` can do on its own using its [`Read` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read).

Answer (score -1):

All data in computer is bytes. The StreamReader can be used for any format files, including text and binary file. In the low level, the ftp sever use socket to send data using bytes. In my view, it's safe to put all data in byte[], and you can interpret them in various ways.

Comment: That's not true. Quoting `StreamRead` docs: *Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding.* It should not be used for binary data.